# Remove empty spaces between cardviews inside GridLayout

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I need help on how to remove the empty spaces between cardViews inside a Grid Layout. The empty space forms below each row of cards.I want to remove this extra space.How do i fix this.I have included a screenshot to clarify this.

Here is my code for my layout XML

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    app:contentPaddingLeft="0dp"
    app:contentPaddingRight="0dp"
    app:contentPaddingTop="0dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
           android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:id="@+id/text_view_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="name"
            android:textSize="11sp"
            android:textAlignment="center" />


        <ImageView
            android:transitionName="@+id/profile"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text_view_name"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/image_view_upload"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

My MainActivity layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:clipToPadding="false"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My java MainActivity class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ImageAdapter.OnItemClickListener {

 private RecyclerView recyclerview;
private ImageAdapter adapter;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  recyclerview = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        adapter = new ImageAdapter(this, uploads);

  recyclerview.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,3));
     recyclerview.setPadding ( 1,1,1,1 );
}
}
```

[Here is a Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNcqK.jpg)

Comment: Remove android:layout_marginTop="50dp" from your cardView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove

```
android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
```

from your CardView

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
android:paddingBottom="0dp"
app:contentPaddingLeft="0dp"
app:contentPaddingRight="0dp"
app:contentPaddingTop="0dp"
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
android:orientation="vertical">
```